# Css style not applying in Internet Explorer, but works well in firefox

Tags: php, css, cross-browser

I am trying to apply css to php code. But it not working well in Internet Explorer, But working fine in firefox

Code :

```
   echo '<div class="resultno">';
   echo "<td>" . $row['stu_id'] . "</td>"." ";
   echo '</div>';
   echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td><br>". " ";
   echo "<br>";
```

And it looks like -->  http://www.flickr.com/photos/41695354@N08/3957144073/

Any suggestions please help

Answer (score 12):

You should not have TD directly inside DIV, it's invalid HTML. TD is supposed to sit inside TR inside TABLE.

When you omit necessary element like that, browser tries to guess what you mean, and who knows what that leads to.

Answering additional question: Guessing what you are trying to do, I'd say that you should get rid of the div and apply the resultno class directly to the TD.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the HTML code is completely broken.

You are putting elements inside the table but outside the table cells. This is not allowed, and different browsers have different ways of interpreting the code to try to make sense of it. That is why you are getting so different results.

A table element contains table rows (tr), which contain table cells (th,td). Inside the table cells you can put other content, but not anywhere else in the table.

Comment: So what i have to do. Please help

Comment: Well, first you have to decide if you are going to use a table or not. From the little code that I have seen I can't even tell what kind of solution you are trying to use...

Answer (score 1):

You need something more like this (as Guffa and buti-oxa said):

```
   echo '<div class="resultno">';
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['stu_id'] . "</td>"." ";
   echo "</tr>"." ";
   echo '</div>';
   echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td><br>". " ";
   echo "<br>";
```

Don't generally program in this language so not 100% if it's correct, but that ought to do it.

Comment: That's still just as broken... It should either be a table with rows and cells, or no table elements at all.

Answer (score 0):

IE has a lot of problems with its interpretation of CSS. See:

[www.haslayout.net](http://www.haslayout.net)

http://www.quirksmode.org/

http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html

...and a variety of others, try to find the specific issue you are experiencing, also try the CSS using straight HTML without any PHP code; you can use a test page like:

http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/html/testbed.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just using DIV elements instead.

Also, to save on single/double quotation complications, you can just break out of PHP when you want, and break back into it to echo the variables. This gives your code much more readability and saves on all the echoes. Also ideal if you are using a program that highlights different languages like PHPedit or something similar.

i.e.

CSS:

```
<style>
  .stuID { float:left; width: 150px; }
  .studName { float:left; width: 300px; } 
</style>
```

HTML & PHP:

```
<?php foreach($array as $row): ?>

    <div class="resultno">
      <div class="stuID"><?=$row['stu_id']?></div>
      <div class="stuName"><?=$row['Name']?></div>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Im guessing at how you want the results to appear on screen, but you get the idea of where I am going with this. Hope I'm not barking up the wrong tree!

Answer (score -2):

not sure about your use of single quotes, try:

```
echo "<div class=\"resultno\">";
```

Comment: No, the single quotes are fine.

Comment: Then Whats the problem. Please anyone say

Comment: The problem was highlighted in buti-oxa's answer. A td must go inside a tr, and a tr must go inside a table -- you cannot put a td directly inside a div.